# How to say Mister (Mrs, Miss, etc.) in Latin

Tags: contemporary-latin

I will mark this question as [contemporary-latin](/questions/tagged/contemporary-latin) because there are obviously not any precise classical equivalents of the titles implied by such English honorifics as Mr (Mister or Master), Mrs (Misses), or Miss.

This is somewhat related to another question about [addressing superiors in Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/493/addressing-a-superior-in-latin?rq=1), but my question here is more practical: **What is the best way of translating a sentence like "Mr. Smith Goes to Washington"?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Daniel Morgan's lexicon](http://www.wyomingcatholiccollege.com/faculty-pages/patrick-owens/lexicon/adumbratio/index.aspx), section 754, gives options for Mister and Misses, but not Miss.

- Mister

  - *dominus* (or *domine* in direct address)
  - *eques* (as in English "sir," used before a name)
- Misses / ma'am

  - *domina* (same for direct address)

The options for Mister are based on suitable words for "knight," and are attested as follows:

> (SEN. Ep. 3, 1: "si ... sic illum amicum vocasti quo modo omnes candidatos 'bonos viros' dicimus, quomodo obvios, si nomen non succurrit, 'dominos' salutamus, hac abierit)  |  1652 TURS. 417, listing members of Parliament Charles I of England attempted to arrest in 1642: "Eques Arthur Haselrig, Domini Pym et Hampden")

Morgan does not provide suitable abbreviations, unfortunately.

Comment: . "At the University of Cambridge, the honorific 'Domina' (abbreviated as Dna) is given to women who hold a Bachelor of Arts degree, but not a master's degree. From mea domina, "my lady," through French "madame," comes "madam", and the contracted form "ma'am." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominus_(title)

Comment: @KenGraham Oh, nice find.  Sounds like a good answer, especially if you can find a source better than WP.

Answer (score 7):

In the notes to *Superbia et Odium*, his translation of *Pride and Prejudice*, Tom Cotton writes,

> Latin has neither appropriate nouns nor convenient abbreviations (Mr, Mrs, etc) by which to indicate social status; to avoid the cumbersome repetition of *Honestior, Matrona* where Jane Austen has used the English abbreviations, I have devised the forms *Hr* and *Mra*. Elsewhere, I have adopted *Hera, Domina,* and *Senior* (Miss, Lady, Sir) to usages which are not strictly classical, but in which the meaning is unambiguous.

As I mentioned in a comment above, Terence Tunberg, who along with Milena Minkova runs the [University of Kentucky Institute for Latin Studies](https://mcl.as.uky.edu/latin-institute), which (as far as I understand) uses Latin as its main language of spoken and written communication, uses *Dominus* for "Mr." and abbreviates it *Dno.* in the dative. If I learn more case abbreviations I'll update this answer.

Comment: Interesting...any idea why [this version of Cotton's translation](http://www.alcuinus.net/ephemeris/superbia.php?id=242) seems to use "Honestus", not "Hera"?

Comment: As I understand it, the book version wasn't published until after he'd finished the online version, so one assumes that in between the two he decided that *Honestior* was better than *Honestus*, and also came up with the abbreviation *Hr*. (He uses *Hera* for "Miss," not for "Mister.")

Answer (score 4):

I have seen *dominus* used for "Mr" in some comics translated to Latin.
Analogously I would use *domina* for "Mrs".
I don't have a good suggestion for "Miss", though.
Perhaps the diminutive *dominula* is better than *virgo* or *puella*.

Therefore I would translate "Mr. Smith Goes to Washington" as ***Dominus Smith Vasitoniam it***.

Comment: I recall seeing *dominus* as well--do you know if it is ever contracted, e.g. *Dn.*?

Comment: @brianpck, I don't recall ever seeing it contracted. If the contraction should distinguish *dominus* and *domina*, perhaps *D:us* and *D:a* would be more likely than *Dn.* or *D.*, but this is just a guess.

Comment: I recently got an email from Terence Tunberg, who runs the living Latin program at the University of Kentucky, that opened with "Terentius Dno. Derfner spd." So I'd say abbreviations are possible.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Weren't "dominus" & "domina" terms of address for high-ranking Romans--"Lord" & "Lady"? The Emperor's wife might be called, "Domina", and ladies of a slightly-lesser ilk. At street level? In Roman-epic movies even people like Senators refer to each-other by their surnames: "Greetings Crassus."; "Are you well, Caesar?".

Comment: @tony As acknowledged in the question, there is no exact classical equivalent to the modern Mr/Mrs, so none of the offered translations will be a perfect match. How to address people above you in ancient Rome is an entirely different question, but a good one.